# header.php content appears inside the body tag on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Can someone help me with this.. im trying to learn to make a wordpress theme from scratch.

[image]

Comment: `hmtl`? Really?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest that you start by following one of the tutorials listed here: http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+a+wordpress+theme

You also have a spelling mistake in some of the html tags.

Comment: @LeeHarveyPelomiana Great. I am happy to hear that. Maybe you should accept the answer so the question is marked as resolved :)